# How can i do autozoom when i receive new values

Tags: reactjs, plotly.js

I have a component with barChart, but i have a socket that i receive new values for this barchart. If the value change from 19 to 200, i must do double click for reset zoom. There are any config for do that automatically?

my plotly config is:

```
layout: {
      autosize: true,
      xaxis: {
        title: bottomText,
        autorange: true
      },
      yaxis: {
        title: leftText,
        autorange: true
      },
      dragmode: 'zoom',
      hovermode: 'closest',
      margin: {
        t:20,
        b: 150
      },
      transition: {
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'cubic-in-out'
      }
    },
  data: [{
      x: details.index,
      y: details.fw,
      type: 'bar'
    }],
  config: {
      displaylogo: false,
      locale: 'es',
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the zoom by assigning a new value to `layout.uirevision` when updating your chart. See https://plot.ly/javascript/uirevision/#reset-user-changes